# DVD Continually Opening Closing

Tags: dvd

I want to disable the DVD which is not used. It now just opens and closes every few minutes. I have tried a few things but nothing works. I cannot easily open up the PC which is under a corner table to change the hardware. Is there anyway to disable the DVD in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to disable it from you bios. Depending on what model computer you have, that should be doable.